# Какая функция у символов \\?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, r

Сорри за глупый/легкий вопрос, но нужно разобраться.Прохожу курс на datacamp, не могу вкурить что за описание:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю последнее предложение - что именно делают символы (\) ?

Comment: Вообще говоря, экранирование в регулярках R - это сложный вопрос с подвохом, так как в base R при использовании движка TRE символьные классы не "понимают" regex escapes  вроде `\s`. В общем же случае, ``"\\"`` =  ``\``, т.е. тот самый буквальный символ обратной косой черты, который используется для задания / формирования "shorthand character classes" (символьных классов) и экранирования специальных метасимволов регулярок.

Comment: сложное для меня описание, но все равно благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильней будет сказать что "\s" с одним слэшем это символ пробела, а пишут два слэша чтобы среда разработки (иде) поняла и схавала. Называется экранированием символа. Хотя в разных языках символ экранирования кажись разный. Бывает и обратный слэш если правильно помню "/\s"

Comment: `/` — это **просто** косая черта (ну или «слэш» на it-жаргоне). а `\ ` — [**обратная**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score -1):

Делают из буквы "s" метасимвол, означающий пробел. Называется "экранирование".

Если в регулярном выражении просто написать "s", то будет искаться буква "s". Если же написать "`\\s`", то будут искаться пробелы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!!!